# LaTeX packages minted and scrhack

Tags: errors, koma-script, minted

I'd like to use the `minted` package and the `scrhack` package in the same LaTeX document, that is:

```
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{minted}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty:215: Package scrhack Error: extension `lol' already in use. [...t{listing}{h}{lol}[\minted@float@within]}]
```

Edit:
The problem was that I used the package `classicthesis` and included both, `listing` and `minted`. I cannot completely replicate the error, but this MWE has a very similar error message:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}



\begin{document}

    Hello, World!

\end{document}
```

The error message is:

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source

/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/listings.hak:136: Package tocbasic Error: file extension `lol' cannot be used twice . [}]
```

Now, I removed `listings` (and all related parts) in the `classicthesis-config.tex` file and everything works fine. I don't think, that I'll need both packages, so my problem is solved.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), please? It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the error seems to be caused by another part, so I'm trying to create a MWE now. Additionally, I should mention, that the error occurred by using the 'classicthesis' package.

Comment: The original error reappears if you put the `\usepackage{listings}` above the others.

Answer (score 12):

The package *scrhack* redefines macros of other packages. It should be loaded at the very end. Luckily the following then already compiles without errors:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{scrhack}

\begin{document}
    Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

If you really need to include *scrhack* somewhere else, you could use the `\AtEndPreamble` hook provided by the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: according to the docs the package should not be loaded at the very end.

"It is recommended to load the scrhack package as early as possible. In particular, loading should be done before the affected packages." (introduction of chapter 16 in [scrguien.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), currently page 414)

Comment: @uvularer_frikativ: Please note that this Q&A is from 2014! The situation today might indeed be quite different. Your comment however does not contain enough information to really understand this in the context of the given situation. Imho as it stands, it is rather confusing. Could you please expand upon it (or delete is also fine with me)?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. actually i just wanted to say that you answer contradicts the (present) komascript docs.
i guess the correct order (according to the docs) is: minted, scrhack, listings.
it would be great if you could update your answer.