# Deferred loading of dependent packages?

Tags: packages, minted

It is known that the package `scrhack` should be loaded as late as possible to avoid some errors. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156240/) for such a problem.

However, when writing a document class or a package, I would like to require packages (without necessarily requiring conflicting packages).

An example illustrates my problem:

```latex
% MyTheme.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\newcommand{\classname}{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[2020/08/24 v1.7 LaTeXTemplates.com]
\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}
\LoadClass{\baseclass}
\RequirePackage{scrhack}
```

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{MyTheme}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[outputdir=build]{minted}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

This will create the following error:

```
scrhack Error: extension `lol' already in use.
```

The problem is solved if I remove `\RequirePackage{scrhack}` in MyTheme.cls, or if I add `\RequirePackage{minted}` before `\RequirePackage{scrhack}`. However, I prefer to keep the dependency on `scrhack` explicit, and don't want to create unnecessary dependencies.

...but how? Is it possible to somehow request a package with `\RequirePackage`, but delay loading it?

Comment: Please complete your class code so we can compile the hole thing ...

Comment: @Mensch Updated my question with a minimal document class.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I found that adding `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{scrhack}}` in the document class solves my problem.

Comment: don't load packages in \AtBeginDocument, hyperref e.g. will simply error if loaded so late. Better use `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{...}`

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that using `\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{packagename}}` delays the loading of required packages. Some comments pointed out even more appropriate hooks.

The following document class also requires the `scrhack` package, but does not cause the problem stated in the OP.

```latex
% MyTheme.cls
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/12/01]
\newcommand{\classname}{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\ProvidesClass{\classname}[2020/08/24 v1.7 LaTeXTemplates.com]
\providecommand{\baseclass}{book}
\LoadClass{\baseclass}

% Deferred loading of package scrhack
% Alternative 1:
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{\usepackage{scrhack}}

% Alternative 2: Uses package etoolbox
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage{biblatex}}

% Alternative 3: Load package at begin{document}, which might be 
% too late for some packages (as has been noted by Ulrike Fischer)
\AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{scrhack}}
```

Comment: See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392175) related post.

Comment: There is also the `\AtEndPreamble` hook from `etoolbox`, which executes a bit earlier than `\AtBeginDocument`.